# IMAP Server does not show received mail

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, imap

I have recently set up a brand new mail server using Dovecot and Postfix, which is correctly sending and receiving mail, with the `/var/mail/` directory mailbox.

Here's the problem: mail cannot be seen via the Roundcube webmail interface, but the mail can easily be accessed using `mutt` and simply looking into your `/var/mail` folder.

Here's where it goes wrong, IMAP does not show that there's anything in the user inbox, even though everything else is working.

IMAP Testing:

```
robo@some-server:~$ telnet localhost imap
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot (Ubuntu) ready.
a1 LOGIN robo yetanotherrandompasswordtofoolyou
a1 OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT MULTIAPPEND URL-PARTIAL CATENATE UNSELECT CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 CONDSTORE QRESYNC ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH LIST-STATUS SPECIAL-USE BINARY MOVE] Logged in
a2 LIST "" "*"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren \Sent) "." Sent
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." INBOX
a2 OK List completed.
a3 EXAMINE INBOX
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] Read-only mailbox.
* 0 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1431224194] UIDs valid
* OK [UIDNEXT 1] Predicted next UID
* OK [NOMODSEQ] No permanent modsequences
a3 OK [READ-ONLY] Examine completed (0.000 secs).
a4 FETCH 1 BODY[]
a4 BAD Error in IMAP command FETCH: Invalid messageset
```

At this same time, there is exactly one message in `/var/mail/robo` that has recently been received.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue:

Dovecot IMAP had not been configured to use the `mbox` mail format, which could simply be corrected by adding the following line to my `/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf`:

```
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
```

In which the `mail_location` had not been specified previously.

Comment: gone through this and may be this might be one option http://www.dovecot.org/list/dovecot/2007-September/025727.html